# <xs:all minOccurs="0" still requires the elements to exist

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I'm writing a Schema for our (old) XML output, and have run into an issue where an element may contain some sub-elements.  I'm using an "xs:all minOccurs="0" in the schema, but when I validate against the XML, it's requiring at least one instance of each sub-element.

```
    <xs:element name="Project">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:element ref="lit:ProductPool" minOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element ref="lit:ProjectDefaults"/>
                <xs:element ref="lit:TaskInfo"/>
            </xs:all>
            <xs:attribute name="Name" type="lit:TextType_2010"/>
... a bunch more
```

Then when I use that to validate some XML that only has the "ProductPool" sub element, the validator complains that the other 2 are missing and are required.

````
    Reason: The following elements are expected after this location (see below)
        'lit:TaskInfo'
        'lit:ProjectDefaults'
    Error location: MetrixXML / Project
    Details
        cvc-complex-type.1.4: The content for element <Project> is incomplete.
        cvc-type.3.2: Element <Project> is not valid with respect to type definition '{anonymous}'.
        cvc-elt.5.2.1: The element <Project> is not valid with respect to the actual type definition '{anonymous}'.```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your MinOccurs is on the All node rather than on the ProjectDefaults or TaskInfo, by default they will be minOccurs once.  So if ProductPool was not there, it will not complain, but as soon as you have ProductPool, it will expect the other two.

Resolve it by setting `MinOccurs = 0` on ProjectDefaults and TaskInfo

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I was thinking the value would get inherited.  Obviously not.

Answer (score 1):

On an [`<xs:element>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#element-element)<sup>*</sup>, the value of attributes `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` both default to `1`.
On an [`<xs:all>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#element-all)<sup>*</sup>, the value of attributes `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` both default to `1`.

<sup>** Click link to see specification*</sup>

That means the follow 3 constructs are the same:

```
<!-- As defined in question -->
<xs:all minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:element ref="lit:ProductPool" minOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element ref="lit:ProjectDefaults"/>
    <xs:element ref="lit:TaskInfo"/>
</xs:all>
```

```
<!-- Without specifying values that are same as defaults -->
<xs:all minOccurs="0">
    <xs:element ref="lit:ProductPool"/>
    <xs:element ref="lit:ProjectDefaults"/>
    <xs:element ref="lit:TaskInfo"/>
</xs:all>
```

```
<!-- Specifying values, even if same as defaults -->
<xs:all minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:element ref="lit:ProductPool" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element ref="lit:ProjectDefaults" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element ref="lit:TaskInfo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xs:all>
```

This means that if the `all` is used in the actual XML, by having any of `ProductPool`, `ProjectDefaults`, or `TaskInfo` present, then **all 3 must be present**.

The `minOccurs="0"` means that you can have none of them, or all three of them.

Perhaps you believed that `minOccurs` defaulted to `0`, in which case you should have written it like this:

```
<xs:all minOccurs="0">
    <xs:element ref="lit:ProductPool"/>
    <xs:element ref="lit:ProjectDefaults" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element ref="lit:TaskInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:all>
```

With such a definition, `ProductPool` is optional, and can appear by itself. `ProjectDefaults` and `TaskInfo` are also optional, but if either is present, then `ProductPool` is required. The three elements can appear in any order.

Comment: So, what is the point of having minOccurs and maxOccurs on the xs:all?
They don't appear to have any effect on anything.

Comment: @CasaDelGato I see no point to having `maxOccurs` on `<xs:all>`, since it defaults to 1 and cannot be higher. The point of `minOccurs` is the ability to make it optional. If you don't specify `minOccurs="0"`, then it is required, which would then make `ProductPool` required.

Comment: Ok, I was (again) getting confused with some comments I read about changes in xsd 1.1 for xs:all.